# Recolor image in Windows 10 Universal App C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, windows-10-universal

Working on an app and as part of it I need to recolour it to match the phones accent color.

What I have is a gray scale image with transparent sections and want to change it the colored.

- The white sections will be the pure accent color
- Gray sections will be the accent color faded
- Black sections will be black

I've done this in the past, but never with a universal app.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt598502.aspx) to apply some basic effects on your image.

If it doesn't fit your requirement. You can use [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) to work on your picture. You can find a good example of Win2D by this link: [Shawn's Terrific Universal App for photogRaph Tweaking](https://github.com/shawnhar/stuart).